# Changing the order of images dynamically in HTML5 - Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a little isometric game.There are objects and players.

In init function;

```
drawObject();
drawPlayer();
```

So in screen player always shown in top of objects because player drawn after objects but it should be like that; if y-coordinate of the object is more than the player's y-coordinate then object must be drawn later and shown on top. Or is there anything like `z-index` property for `drawImage()` function for canvas?

Comment: Exactly as Jonas said, no, there isn't.  If you want things to be drawn on top of each other in a specific order, you will have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no z-index property for the Canvas. The canvas will be drawn in the order you code your drawing primitives.